# How can I add authentication when using the Logic App action?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-logic-apps

How can I add authentication when using the Logic App action?

The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-nested-logic-apps) around using the action for nesting only detail making the call; nothing on adding any authentication.

I know I can use the "raw" HTTP action, but this goes HTTP, whereas the Logic App action goes direct to the workflow, i.e. no HTTP. And this means you can NOT enable the Access Control setting to limit calls to only other logic apps when run in an ISE.

We also want to move away from using the SAS key in the logic app URL, over to using the Azure AD OAuth authorisation policies for management of the authorisation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time (2020-10-28), there is no way to add OAuth authentication to the Logic App action

You have to use the HTTP action in the logic app, which allows you to add an Authentication parameter

You can then select the Authentication Type from ...

- None
- Basic
- Client Certificate
- Active Directory OAuth  *(i.e. Service Principal)*
- Raw
- Managed Identity  *(i.e. either User or System Assigned Managed Identity)*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move away from using the SAS key in the logic app URL, over to using the Azure AD OAuth authorisation policies for management of the authorisation, the best way to do it would be through [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/api-management/).